# Initializing Function Pointer of .lib outside the library in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I think this is a trivial question, but I am never able to get this to work!

I have made a function call through a function pointer inside a .lib and attached the .lib to an application program which sets the function pointer, outside the library. The following is the code snippet

Lib :

```
void (*PopulateBuffer)(byte *NALBuffer,unsigned int *readbytes); // The Declaration

PopulateBuffer(NALBuffer,&readbytes); // The function Call
```

Application :

```
extern void (*PopulateBuffer)(char *NALBuffer,unsigned int *readbytes);


void UpdateNALBuff(char *Buffer,unsigned int *readbytes)

{

    //Buffer content is updated
    //readbytes is updated

}

main()

{

    PopulateBuffer= &UpdateNALBuff;

        LibMain(); // this is the main call in which the function pointer is called
}
```

Am I doing this right???
Cause when ever the function call approaches in the library, it throws me the following error :

> Unhandled exception at 0x00536e88 in DecoderTestApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x7ffef045.

Comment: The library is static and not .dll

Comment: Is it failing at calling the function with pointer or inside the function?

Comment: its failing at the function call, not inside the function I have placed a breakpoint inside the function, and it does not reach that point, I get the error at the function call

Comment: In that case, try to debug caller of the function, using source code of library or by assembly and check exactly what is those addresses are.

Comment: could you try changing it to a `void PopulateBuffer(void)` function that only prints something to check if the error isn't elsewhere?

Comment: Yup, tried the same, and still getting the same error...

Comment: how is 'byte' defined? unsigned char?

Comment: and is the buffer you read into, large enough? 'NALBuffer'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally for dealing with function pointers, you do it in the following way:

```
typedef void (*PopulateBuffer)(byte *NALBuffer,unsigned int *readbytes); //This should be exposed from the library
```

Create a pointer variable inside the library for storing the function pointer

```
PopulateBuffer PpBuffFunc = NULL;
```

Provide a function from the library to set the function

```
void setPopulateBufferFuncPointer(PopulateBuffer func)
{
    PpBuffFunc = func;
}
```

Now call this function from your application

```
setPopulateBufferFuncPointer(UpdateNALBuff);
```

Inside the lib at appropriate place, call the `PpBuffFunc` by passing appropriate parameters

Comment: Hey! .. found it ! .. i was calling the function in another file and hadn't given the prototype for the same in that file thus it was taking the return value as "int" rather than "void"! :).. thankyou, your approach was very very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok, however I suspect the buffer that you read into is too small
and that is why you are getting access violation.

```
void UpdateNALBuff(char *Buffer,unsigned int *readbytes)
{
   //put values in Buffer but no more than *readbytes passed in,
   //finally update *readbytes with actual number of bytes read.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

got it! :)

The problem was, I was calling the function pointer in another file without providing prototype for the same,

Thus it was taking the "return type" as INT, and as the function was of the return type void,
an error was being thrown! .. it was a silly mistake! 
Thanks every one! :)